# Write to a file without read permission

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-permissions, acl

I'm trying to Implement The Bell-La Padula Model on local windows accounts in C# , and in this model the user in lower security level can write to files that belong to higher security level without read it !!
I've Added permissions to files like this

> file.txt : read [deny] - write [Allow]

Now I'm working on allow user to append text to file.txt without read it .
I used this :

```
using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Modified BY :" + username + Environment.NewLine);
                    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                    sw.WriteLine("---------- END User Edition --------------");
                }
```

It worked when I run The program from the Admin account ,but when I tried to run it from Guset account it raise exception : you can't access this file !

I've tried to add read permissions before Start Editing and remove it after finish , but the the file permissions never changed .

Is there any programmatic way that I can implement that , or allow my application to make effect on file when run it within Guest account ?

Answer (score 2):

Took a little time but got it figured out. Had to use procmon to figure it out. Your code is fine. However, you need to setup permissions properly.

For your text file, you need to grant the limited account rights to Write only. Do not check anything under the deny column. Because if you do, the deny access will trump anything else. You also need to grant that account access to **Read Attributes** and **Read Extended Attributes** permissions as well.

You can probably accomplish the same thing using `icacls` or `cacls`. Here are the manual instructions on how to do it manually. This is based on Windows 10 (Win7 should be similar):

1. Right click on the file
2. click on properties.
3. switch to Security tab.
4. Click on "Edit" button
5. Click on "Add..." button
6. Find the limited user account.
7. Back in the permissions tab, select the account.
8. uncheck everything except "Write" checkbox.
     [image]
9. Click "OK" to close this dialog box.
10. Click on "Advanced" button.
11. Select the account and click "Edit" button.
12. On the next dialog box, click "Show advanced permissions"
      [image]
13. Make sure that the following check boxes are checked.

    - Read Attributes
    - Read extended attributes
    - Create files / write data
    - Create folders / append data
    - Write attributes
    - Write extended attributes

      [image]
14. Click OK on all the dialog boxes.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. In my case I wanted to do that on a network share so I had to give Full Control to Everybody to have that working.

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically, you need to allow these:

```
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.AppendData
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.CreateFiles
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.WriteExtendedAttributes
```

[Extra info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Read/Write(Extended)Attributes` are necessary for write operations, above will let users to create log files and append text to them without being able to read anything, If you add `Delete` permission, that will make rolling of the log files possible as well (i'd say most of people will need it as having unlimited size logs without rolling is quite dangerous)

This can be done via any .NET language, PowerShell example (create and write logs files and roll them permissions):

```
$acl = Get-Acl "C:\logs"

$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false) # Remove inherited
$acl.Access | % { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) } | Out-Null # Remove existing
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("SYSTEM", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")))

$logsRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::AppendData -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::CreateFiles -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Delete -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ReadAttributes -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ReadExtendedAttributes -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::WriteAttributes -bor `
              [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::WriteExtendedAttributes

$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users", $logsRights, "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")))
Set-Acl "C:\logs" $acl
Write-Host "logs ACL"
$acl.Access
```

Depending on your use case you may or may not need to clear existing rules and add SYSTEM/Administrators, but you get the idea